# How to create a unique ID on each function call to a drop down list Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to dynamically add a new product each time an option from a drop down menu is chosen. However I believe my id field is preventing me from creating new data on my added rows. I can only change the first row. How to adjust my script to create ne id values on each function call. I tried using the Date.Now field.....but no luck.

This is how the form looks
[image: THis is the simple form that should add a product]

Drop down menu
[image]

Added two more products but cant get the values of the Description, Price, etc
[image]

```
@page
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model DotComFinal.Pages.Quotations.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create Quotation</h1>

<hr />
 <div>       
    Customer Info

    <form method="post d-flex">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.Customer.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.Customer.FirstName" class="form-control w-50" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerID"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.Customer.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.Customer.LastName" class="form-control w-50" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerID"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.Customer.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.Customer.Email" class="form-control w-50" asp-items="ViewBag.CustomerID"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group w-100">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.QuotDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.QuotDate" class="form-control w-50" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quotation.QuotDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.ValidUntil" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.ValidUntil" class="form-control w-50" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quotation.ValidUntil" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

    <div class=" w-50">
        <label class="control-label">Select a Product</label>

        <table id="product-select" class=" table table-striped table-sm w-100">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>

                        <label asp-for="Product[0].Name"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].Description"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].Quantity"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].UnitPrice"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].Discount"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].Vat"> </label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <label asp-for="Product[0].NetTotal"></label>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="btn btn-success  " id="productOptions" onchange="changeDropDownValue()">
                           @* <option value="">Product</option>*@
                            @foreach (var product in Model.Product)
                            {
                                <option value="@product.ID">@product.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].Description" id="test" disabled />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].Quantity" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].UnitPrice" disabled />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].UnitPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].Discount" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].Discount" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].Vat" disabled />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].Vat"  class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="Product[0].NetTotal" disabled />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product[0].NetTotal"  class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <ttd>

                    </ttd>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        @*        <button onclick="AddItem(this)" id="btnadd" type="button" class=" btn btn-sm btn-outline-success m-auto visible">Add Product</button>
        <button id="btnremove" type="button" class="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-danger invisible">Delete</button>*@
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="AddItem(this)" id="btnadd" type="button" class=" btn btn-sm btn-outline-success  w-100 visible">Add Product</button>
    <button onclick="DeleteItem(this)" id="btnremove" type="button" class="m-2 btn btn-sm btn-danger visible">Delete</button>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create Quotation" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" />

            <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
        <div>

    </div>
   
        <div class="d-flex gap-lg-5 ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.StaffID"  class="control-label"></label>
@*                <select asp-for="Quotation.StaffID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.CompanyStaffNameSL"><option value="">-- Select Major --</option></select>
*@            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quotation.FinalTotal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quotation.FinalTotal" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quotation.FinalTotal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
            </form>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");};
}

          <script type="text/javascript">
              function AddItem(btn){
                 var product = document.getElementById("product-select");
                    var rows = product.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length-1].outerHTML;
                    var newRow = product.insertRow();
                 newRow.innerHTML=rowOuterHtml;
          
                 function DeleteItem(btn){
                     var product = document.getElementById("product-select");
                var rows = product.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                     $(btn).closet("tr").remove;
                 }
              }
          </script>
    <script>
        alert("test")

     


        function changeDropDownValue() {
                var selectedProductId = document.getElementById("productOptions").value;
                var Products = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.Product)));
                // Find the product with the matching ID in the Model.Product array
                var selectedProduct = Products.find(product => product.ID == selectedProductId);
                var newId = "product-" + Date.now();
                // Update the input fields with the values of the selected product
                document.getElementById("test").value = selectedProduct.Description;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[0].Quantity")[0].value = selectedProduct.Quantity;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[0].UnitPrice")[0].value = selectedProduct.UnitPrice;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[0].Discount")[0].value = selectedProduct.Discount;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[0].Vat")[0].value = selectedProduct.Vat;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[0].NetTotal")[0].value = selectedProduct.NetTotal;
                
        }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you are just copy a row rather than creating a row with new data in `AddItem(btn)`.Can you explain more about what you want to do?Such as unique id,Date.Now,which is not found in your code.

Comment: When I click on Add Product button this should create a new row that enables me to choose a product. What should then happen i I want to choose the product from the select list and prepopulate the data. However this only happens on the first row not the newly added ones.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,id should be unique,so you need to change the ids when inserting a new row.Then when selcted option is changed,you need to tell the js which row you are changing,so you need to tell the index,here is a demo:

html of select(pass the select element to js,and add the current index into id):

```
 <select class="btn btn-success  " id="productOptions_0" onchange="changeDropDownValue(this)">
                           @* <option value="">Product</option>*@
                            @foreach (var product in Model.Product)
                            {
                                <option value="@product.ID">@product.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

description input(remove the id so that it will be unique when adding new rows):

js:

```
function AddItem(btn){
                 var product = document.getElementById("product-select");
                    var rows = product.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    var rowOuterHtml = rows[1].outerHTML;
                    var index=rows.length-1;//index of the new row
                    var newRow = product.insertRow();
                 newRow.innerHTML=rowOuterHtml.replaceAll("[0","["+index).replaceAll("_0","_"+index);//set ids and names of the new row with index
          
              }

                 function DeleteItem(btn){
                     var product = document.getElementById("product-select");
                var rows = product.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                     $(btn).closet("tr").remove;
                 }
function changeDropDownValue() {
                var selectedProductId = document.getElementById("productOptions").value;
                var Products = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@Model.Product)));
                // Find the product with the matching ID in the Model.Product array
                var selectedProduct = Products.find(product => product.ID == selectedProductId);
                var index=$(test).attr("id").split("_")[1];//find the index with id
                // Update the input fields with the values of the selected product
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].Description")[0].value = selectedProduct.Description;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].Quantity")[0].value = selectedProduct.Quantity;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].UnitPrice")[0].value = selectedProduct.UnitPrice;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].Discount")[0].value = selectedProduct.Discount;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].Vat")[0].value = selectedProduct.Vat;
                document.getElementsByName("Product[" + index + "].NetTotal")[0].value = selectedProduct.NetTotal;
                
        }
```